# woocommerce display order summary email message

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I know there is a woocommerce function to display the table with the order details the admin receives once a new order has been placed but I can't find it anymore.
I'm talking about the 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:' email message which is found in templates/email/admin-new-order.php

Any clue?

Comment: just follow the `email_order_items_table` method and you will see that the table use `emails/email-order-items.php` and `emails/plain/email-order-items.php`